# Bigquery Slot metrics are not showing data in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was trying to create the metrics for the Bigquery and when choosing the slots utilized or related to slots I was not able to get the data as shown in the below:

[image]

Kindly help me how to check this kind of issues in order to populate the data and create metrics on slots. Also I am facing the similar issues with the tables metric.

Comment: Do you have committed slots?

Comment: i was not aware of the process to committed slots can you please help how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Big Query metric `"slots/assigned"`  you are trying to use to create the chart in metric explorer is marked as EARLY_ACCESS as you can follow in [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery) Cloud Monitoring document.

You will need to be invited or whitelisted to use this Alpha metric or wait till it is General Available or in Beta stage.

> Early access: Early access features are limited to a closed group of
> testers for a limited subset of launches. Participation is by
> invitation only and may require signing a pre-general-availability
> agreement, including confidentiality provisions. These features may be
> unstable, change in backward-incompatible ways, and are not guaranteed
> to be released. There are no SLAs provided and no technical support
> obligations. Early access releases are rare and focus on validating
> product prototypes.

If you are not able to see any metric, please take a look if you have the correct [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#before_you_begin) to create those charts in monitoring.

Comment: thanks , but still for the other slot metrics also i was not able to get the data for them,like slots/allocated , slots/allocated_for_project .can you please help

Comment: Hello, please see the second answer too that is valuable information plus the fact that I can see in your graphic the time frame for the data points in the dashboard is to short. You can try by zooming in and out the timestamp to adjust the datapoints values, please take a look at this document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#metrics and the known issues to have more idea of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, BigQuery is a serverless product, you pay what you use (here, the volume of data scanned). To process the data, slots are assigned. You have, by default 2000 slots assigned to your project.

The problem with this pattern is the not predictability of the cost, which is problematic in large company (who prefer to pay more with a knows budget in advance -> stupid, but financial departments prefer!!). For this, you can [reserve your slots](Cluster Program Manager) and you can assign them to different project (if you have reserved slots at Organisation level and not at project level).

With slot, you no longer pay the volume of data scanned, but only your slots.
*Of course, if your query takes 10s with 2000 slots and you assign only 500 slots, the query will take 40s (it's not so linear, but it the principle)*

You can dynamically change the assignation if you want. I mean, if you have a project with batch process the night, you can assign the max of slots to it during the night, and reassign the slots during the day for your dashboarding project (for example).

So, with this metrics, you can follow the slots assignation to your project. The other interesting metrics in the allocated slots. Indeed, you can set 500 slots to your project, but your query require only 100 slots. Like this you can optimise your assignations.